# How to avoid for-in looping over None in Python

Tags: python

I know I can add some `if` blocks around to avoid this problem, but I am looking for a best practice or good/nice way to handle this kind of programming problem.

I am looping through the result of a function, without storing the result first in a separate variable; something like this:

```
for item in mycustimitemgetter.itter():
   dosomething()
```

The `itter` function is returning `None` instead of an empty list `[]`, and Python throws an exception per `None`. This is correct python behavior and nothing's wrong with it. But I'm looking for a best practice solution to:

a) keep the code clean and simple (not storing the result in a var and do if != None, etc..)

b) treat a `None` return value like an empty list i.e. do not run the loop and silently ignore the fact that function returned a `None` value.

Comment: Or show what you consider is an ugly and maybe we'll produce a prettier version for you.

Comment: Which function is returning the `None`?  The method `itter()`?

Comment: Edited in clarification about what is returning None.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Perhaps, use the fact that both `[]` and `None` evaluate as False, but lists with contents don't:

```
for item in (mycustimitemgetter.itter() or []):
   dosomething()
```

Comment: I don't think that's very good practice. If you provide a function that returns an iterable, it should return an iterable in all cases.

Comment: Parentheses around xxx or yy are redundant.

Comment: @Joe: I agree, hence the "perhaps". Anyway we don't know exactly what `itter` is. I thought I'd just give a factual answer and not assume too much.

Comment: @qarma: Feel free to leave them out, to me it looked a little bit more clear this way.

Comment: the point is the "mycustimitemgetter.itter()" function is just a placeholder for many functions I use. Normally I face this problem when extracting content from xml and looping trough tags. But if there is no such tag, I just want to ignore this fact. So I think the idea RemcoGerlich provided does pretty much what i need.

Comment: @manuel: at least, keep in mind that many itemgetters take a "default" argument, and you can often tell them to use `[]` as a default. More explicit, thus better.

Comment: it seems that this kind of check is deprecated: FutureWarning: The behavior of this method will change in future versions. Use specific 'len(elem)' or 'elem is not None' test instead.

Comment: To find the reason for that, it's going to be important exactly what `mycustomitemgetter` and its `.itter()` *are*...

Comment: Nice.........!!

Answer (score 9):

You have a method called `itter()` which returns an iterable object. I would say that given the name of the function, it's reasonable to say "the returned value should always be iterable". So, if you're returning a list, you should return an empty list if you have no values.

Code there to be executed. There is nothing wrong with adding:

```
if retval is None:
  return []
return retval
```

or

```
return retval or []
```

to the end of your `itter()` implementation, depending on the types in use.

Consider this: you wrote the code and you're facing this problem. What about someone else who's trying to use your code without knowing what you know. What do they expect?

Alternatively you should use [Generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) (if suitable). They contain a 'next' method (see the docs at the link), which you can return false if there are no values.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I was looking for the "... or []: " statement.

Comment: Make sure you use it properly. Lots of things evaluate as 'falsy' in Python.

Comment: Or use the Ternary Operator in Python 2.5+. e.g. `return retval if retval is not None else []` or if you prefer `return [] if retval is None else retval`.